# why is there a double "が" here: "... 岐阜県警が捜索したが見つからず、..."?

Tags: grammar, translation, particles, syntax, particle-が

From the newspaper article titles [北アルプス・涸沢岳で２人滑落、１人行方不明](http://www.yomiuri.co.jp/national/20150430-OYT1T50157.html), the second paragraph reads:

> 男性１人が行方不明となり、岐阜県警がヘリコプターで捜索したが見つからず、同日夕、日没のため打ち切った。１日午前から捜索を再開する。

my guess of a translation:

> Being that there is one man whose location is unknown, (security / police) from Gifu prefecture searched in a helicopter for him, and without his being found, they called-off the search due to sundown. From the morning of the first of May, the search will resume."

at the least, what I don't understand is the following:
"... *捜索したが見つからず* 、... "

could I segment the sentence as follows:
"男性１人が行方不明となり、岐阜県警がヘリコプターで捜索した **ん** が、**行方不明な人が** 見つからず、...."

Even if the explanation is "that is just how newspapers write (in order to save space)", would not it read more easily and sound more natural to add just a single comma as such:
"... *岐阜県警が捜索したが、見つからず* 、... "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second が in the snippet 岐阜県警が捜索したが見つからず is not the subject marker, but the conjunction particle が (which you could replace by け(れ)ど(も)) translating to "but":

> 岐阜県警が捜索した**が**見つからず
>   Gifu Police searched [for the missing person], **but** not finding [him, had to call off the search the same evening...]

I don't understand your "sentence segment", so I can't comment on it, but in any case I agree that the sentence might be a tad easier to parse with a comma after the が. That said, the commas in the sentence are standard newspaper style: commas after the omitted conjunction (after なり) and after the ず; and after 同日夕 for easy reading.